# Single noun that encompasses both writer and speaker

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, writing, speech

While writing and speaking are two different skill sets, they have much in common, and there are many people highly skilled in both. For instance, Garrison Keillor is both an excellent writer and an excellent speaker. An orator is someone skilled in writing. An adjective for such a person might be "eloquent." Perhaps there is such a word in another language. But I have not been able to think of a good word that encompasses both--a noun for someone who is good with words in whatever form they might come. The definition would be something like, "One who is eloquent." "Communicator" seems too broad, somehow.

Comment: 'Storyteller' or a synonym like a chronicler could work situation-ally.  Garrison Keillor is certainly a storyteller. Ken Burns is more of chronicler. Both of those words could be used for more mediums than writing and speaking... film in the case of Ken Burns.

Comment: Maybe *wordsmith?*

Comment: The first word that came to my mind was communicator, but it's not exclusive to writing and speaking, as you mentioned. Will be very surprised (and intrigued) if someone manages to find a word that applies just to written and spoken word!

Comment: Perhaps *elucidator*.

Comment: An "orator" is someone skilled in writing? An orator is someone skilled in orating (i.e., opening his or her mouth and speaking).

Comment: @rhetorician I only just now noticed your username. I honestly didn't provide the answer I did because of this. Although it's ironic that you didn't think of it. :)

Comment: @JasonBassford: I'm red-faced about this one! I unvoted you. Don

Answer (score 2):

The word [**rhetorician**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhetorician) applies specifically to both writer and speaker:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2** : an eloquent or grandiloquent writer or speaker